# JAVA - Polymorphism trouble

Tags: java, polymorphism, overriding

As a homework I'm creating a SingleLinkedNode class that implements a Node interface.

Node Interface

```
 public interface Node <T> {

    static final String NULL_NODE_ERROR = "Node can't be null";

    public void setNextNode(Node nextNode) throws NullPointerException;
    public void setIndex(int index);
    public int getIndex();
    public T getData();
    public Node getNextNode();

   }
```

SingleLinkedNode class

```
public class SingleLinkedNode<T> implements Node<T> {

    private int index;
    private T data;
    private SingleLinkedNode nextNode;

    public SingleLinkedNode() {
    }

    public SingleLinkedNode(int index) {
        this.index = index;
    }

    public SingleLinkedNode(int index, SingleLinkedNode nextNode) {
        this.index = index;
        this.nextNode = nextNode;
    }

    @Override
    public void setNextNode(SingleLinkedNode nextNode) throws NullPointerException{
        if (nextNode == null){
            throw new NullPointerException(NULL_NODE_ERROR);
        }

        this.nextNode = nextNode;
    }

    @Override
    public void setIndex (int index){
        this.index = index;
    }

    @Override
    public int getIndex() {
        return this.index;
    }

    @Override
    public T getData() {
        return this.data;
    }

    @Override
    public SingleLinkedNode getNextNode() {
        return this.nextNode;
    }

}
```

In the setNextNode(SingleLinkedNode nextNode) method of the class it says that I'm not implementing the setNextNode(Node nextNode) method of the interface even though SingleLinkedNode implements Node.

But if I leave the class method exactly as the interface one it says that Node can't be converted to SingleLinkedNode, pretty obvious.

Is there any right way of overriding this method and being sure that the method only accepts SingleLinkedNode objects as arguments?

I thought about casting but I'm not sure if that the right way.

Comment: Look at the `Object` class's `equals` method and try override it. You can't change the argument type other than `Object` itself. Simply change `public void setNextNode(SingleLinkedNode nextNode)` to `public void setNextNode(Node nextNode)` will solve the problem and you can check `SingleLinkedNode` using `nextNode instanceof  SingleLinkedNode` and can throw exception if not matched

Comment: You are missing generic parameters in lots of places.  Clean that up first.

Comment: @JimGarrison what do you mean? Can you point an example? Thanks

Comment: Please correct your program as  public void setNextNode(Node nextNode)

Comment: `Node` should be generic or parameterized like `Node<T>` wherever used in the code like as method arguments, return type and field declarations etc. Add one more check in overridden method `setNextNode` like `if(!(nextNode instanceof SingleLinkedNode)){ throw new IllegalArgumentException("Only single link list node is accepted"); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all the solution was as follows

```
@Override
    public void setNextNode(Node nextNode) throws NullPointerException, IllegalArgumentException{
        if (nextNode == null){
            throw new NullPointerException(NULL_NODE_ERROR);
        }
        if ( ! (nextNode instanceof SingleLinkedNode) ) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Node is not SingleLinkedNode");
        }

        this.nextNode = (SingleLinkedNode) nextNode;
    }
```